# Count of occurrences horizontally

Tags: r

I have the following table:

```
Fashion       Travel       Home        Electronics Toys
Y             N            N           N           N     
N             N            N           Y           N     
Y             Y            Y           Y           N     
Y             N            N           N           N     
Y             Y            Y           Y           Y     
Y             Y            N           Y           Y
```

I need to count the number of occurrences of "Y" in a row and store it in a "Filter" column.

The result should be as follows.

```
Fashion       Travel       Home        Electronics Toys Filter
Y             N            N           N           N    1 
N             N            N           Y           N    1 
Y             Y            Y           Y           N    4 
Y             N            N           N           N    1 
Y             Y            Y           Y           Y    5
Y             Y            N           Y           Y    4
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use rowSums:

```
#data
df <- read.table(text = "Fashion       Travel       Home        Electronics Toys
Y             N            N           N           N     
N             N            N           Y           N     
Y             Y            Y           Y           N     
Y             N            N           N           N     
Y             Y            Y           Y           Y     
Y             Y            N           Y           Y", header = TRUE)


#add filter column
df$Filter <- rowSums(df == "Y")

#result
df
#   Fashion Travel Home Electronics Toys Filter
# 1       Y      N    N           N    N      1
# 2       N      N    N           Y    N      1
# 3       Y      Y    Y           Y    N      4
# 4       Y      N    N           N    N      1
# 5       Y      Y    Y           Y    Y      5
# 6       Y      Y    N           Y    Y      4
```

Answer (score 1):

We can also use

```
df1$Filter <- Reduce(`+`,lapply(df1, `==`, "Y"))
df1$Filter
#[1] 1 1 4 1 5 4
```

Comment: You are encouraging lazyness of OP.

Comment: Somebody blatantly abusing their voting power.

Comment: These questions are posted by somebody else.  It's a matter of choice whether to answer a question or not.  I like to help people in dire conditions.  I believe, this answer will help the OP.

Comment: @Pascal http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255459/is-it-okay-to-downvote-answers-to-bad-questions , in other words use your powers to kill the question.

Comment: @zx8754 Looks like we have to additionally follow Pascal's guidelines too :-)

Comment: @Pascal you can vote however you wish, it is your vote. I am simply pointing to a relevant meta post.

Comment: OK. Time for me to quit all of this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `stringr` package

```
    df$Filter <- apply(df, 1, function(i) sum(str_count(i, "Y")))
     df
#     x y Filter
#   1 Y N     1
#   2 N N     0
#   3 Y N     1
#   4 Y Y     2
```

Comment: Ok, I get. It makes more sense if the question was put on hold as incomplete though. Question on hold - Discourages OP from being lazy. Downvoting answers - Encourages others to be lazy

Comment: @Sotos I completely agree with you.  This kind of downvoting authentic answers is abuse of voting power.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `apply` function to find the `length` of `Y`s in every row

```
df$Filter <- apply(df, 1, function(x) length(which(x=='Y')))


#    Fashion Travel Home Electronics Toys Filter
#1       Y      N    N           N    N      1
#2       N      N    N           Y    N      1
#3       Y      Y    Y           Y    N      4
#4       Y      N    N           N    N      1
#5       Y      Y    Y           Y    Y      5
#6       Y      Y    N           Y    Y      4
```